# Look up the servers ips and compare them

Tags: networking, ip

For the self study purpose, I want to understand my company's network. I click Network in my desktop, there are three servers: "hqiz01.corporate.my.com", "ISLAND01"(It is an EMC ISLAND01 storage) and "AD003".

I typed the following commands to check with their ip address.

```
  C:\Windows\System32>nslookup hqiz01.corporate.my.com
  Server:  ad003.corporate.my.com
  Address:  10.10.40.101

  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name:    hqiz01.corporate.my.com.my.com
  Address:  24.29.135.73


  C:\Windows\System32>nslookup ISLAND01
  Server:  ad003.corporate.my.com
  Address:  10.10.40.101

  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name:    ISLAND01.my.com
  Address:  24.29.135.73


  C:\Windows\System32>nslookup AD003
  Server:  ad003.corporate.my.com
  Address:  10.10.40.101
```

You see that they have the same ip address "10.10.40.101". Can we say that the three servers are same?

But why they are all listed in the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 10.10.40.101 ip address is not the ip address of the servers you looked up, it's the ip address of the server that nslookup is using to resolve the queries.

C:\Windows\System32>nslookup hqiz01.corporate.my.com

Server:  ad003.corporate.my.com

Address:  10.10.40.101 - **This is the ip address of the server answering your query**

Non-authoritative answer:

Name:    hqiz01.corporate.my.com.my.com

Address:  24.29.135.73 - **this is the ip address of the server you queried for**

Comment: For both "Non-authoritative answer", they have the same ip "24.29.135.73", are the two servers same? And what is the ip for "AD003"?

Comment: Yes, they are likely the same. You'd have to ask someone who's actually responsible for these devices to get confirmation. Please read the "help" link at the top of this page.

Comment: It's in the nslookup output: Server: ad003.corporate.my.com Address:  10.10.40.101